# How can I get started with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible at the moment? Can someone point good resources? All I can find are different slides "rails4 is cool". Or should I stick to rails3?

Comment: I'd recommend to start with 3.2 and start trying 4.0 when the first release candidate is shipping. Otherwise you might run into gem incompatibilities sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 4 is way new and there's not going to be a lot of resources to gather from at the moment. But you can start by going to:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html

Answer (score 2):

If you're learning rails, I'd say go ahead with it.  If you're building an app, ya might want to wait.  The community has somewhat not gotten around to updating many of the common gems to support the new version yet, so you might have some frustration getting lots of functionality going.

Answer (score 1):

This goes quite a distance to give a quick overview: http://blog.wyeworks.com/2012/11/13/rails-4-compilation-links/